# Return Capacity Values, Not Percent

Tags: objective-c, iphone, battery

Using this method here how would I return the curCapacity and maxCapacity mAh values rather than a percent?

http://blog.coriolis.ch/2009/02/14/reading-the-battery-level-programmatically/comment-page-1/#comment-6089

No matter what I try my curCapacity and maxCapacity values match my battery percentage!

My 1st attempt

```
#include "IOPowerSources.h"
#include "IOPSKeys.h"

- (double) batteryLevel // Find current charge percentage
{
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
    return 80.0f;
#else
    CFTypeRef blob = IOPSCopyPowerSourcesInfo();
    CFArrayRef sources = IOPSCopyPowerSourcesList(blob);

    CFDictionaryRef pSource = NULL;
    const void *psValue;

    int numOfSources = CFArrayGetCount(sources);
    if (numOfSources == 0) {
        NSLog(@"Error in CFArrayGetCount");
        return -1.0f;
    }

    for (int i = 0 ; i < numOfSources ; i++)
    {
            pSource = IOPSGetPowerSourceDescription(blob,     CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(sources, i));
        if (!pSource) {
            NSLog(@"Error in IOPSGetPowerSourceDescription");
            return -1.0f;
        }
        psValue = (CFStringRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(pSource, CFSTR(kIOPSNameKey));

        int curCapacity = 0;
        int maxCapacity = 0;
        double percent;

        psValue = CFDictionaryGetValue(pSource, CFSTR(kIOPSCurrentCapacityKey));
        CFNumberGetValue((CFNumberRef)psValue, kCFNumberSInt32Type, &curCapacity);

        psValue = CFDictionaryGetValue(pSource, CFSTR(kIOPSMaxCapacityKey));
        CFNumberGetValue((CFNumberRef)psValue, kCFNumberSInt32Type, &maxCapacity);

        percent = ((double)curCapacity/(double)maxCapacity * 100.0f);

        return percent;
    }
    return -1.0f;
#endif
}


#include "IOPowerSources.h"
#include "IOPSKeys.h"

- (double) curCapacity // Find current capacity
{
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
    return 460;
    #else
    CFTypeRef blob = IOPSCopyPowerSourcesInfo();
    CFArrayRef sources = IOPSCopyPowerSourcesList(blob);

    CFDictionaryRef pSource = NULL;
    const void *psValue;

    int numOfSources = CFArrayGetCount(sources);
    if (numOfSources == 0) {
        NSLog(@"Error in CFArrayGetCount");
        return -1.0f;
    }

    for (int i = 0 ; i < numOfSources ; i++)
    {
        pSource = IOPSGetPowerSourceDescription(blob,     CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(sources, i));
        if (!pSource) {
            NSLog(@"Error in IOPSGetPowerSourceDescription");
            return -1.0f;
        }
        psValue = (CFStringRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(pSource, CFSTR(kIOPSNameKey));

        int curCapacity = 0;
        int maxCapacity = 0;
        double curCapacityVal;

        psValue = CFDictionaryGetValue(pSource, CFSTR(kIOPSCurrentCapacityKey));
        CFNumberGetValue((CFNumberRef)psValue, kCFNumberSInt32Type, &curCapacity);

        psValue = CFDictionaryGetValue(pSource, CFSTR(kIOPSMaxCapacityKey));
        CFNumberGetValue((CFNumberRef)psValue, kCFNumberSInt32Type, &maxCapacity);

        curCapacityVal = (double)curCapacity;

        return curCapacityVal;
    }
    return -1.0f;
#endif
}




#include "IOPowerSources.h"
#include "IOPSKeys.h"

- (double) maxCapacity // Find maximum capacity
{
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
    return 780;
#else
    CFTypeRef blob = IOPSCopyPowerSourcesInfo();
    CFArrayRef sources = IOPSCopyPowerSourcesList(blob);

    CFDictionaryRef pSource = NULL;
    const void *psValue;

    int numOfSources = CFArrayGetCount(sources);
    if (numOfSources == 0) {
        NSLog(@"Error in CFArrayGetCount");
        return -1.0f;
    }

    for (int i = 0 ; i < numOfSources ; i++)
    {
        pSource = IOPSGetPowerSourceDescription(blob,     CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(sources, i));
        if (!pSource) {
            NSLog(@"Error in IOPSGetPowerSourceDescription");
            return -1.0f;
        }
        psValue = (CFStringRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(pSource, CFSTR(kIOPSNameKey));

        int curCapacity = 0;
        int maxCapacity = 0;
        double maxCapacityVal;

        psValue = CFDictionaryGetValue(pSource, CFSTR(kIOPSCurrentCapacityKey));
        CFNumberGetValue((CFNumberRef)psValue, kCFNumberSInt32Type, &curCapacity);

        psValue = CFDictionaryGetValue(pSource, CFSTR(kIOPSMaxCapacityKey));
        CFNumberGetValue((CFNumberRef)psValue, kCFNumberSInt32Type, &maxCapacity);

        maxCapacityVal = (double)maxCapacity;

        return maxCapacityVal;

    }
    return -1.0f;
#endif
}
```

Comment: Be aware that all of the APIs used here are undocumented on the iPhone, and will probably lead to a rejection if you submit this application to the App Store.  I'd recommend abandoning support for 2.x and using the new UIDevice battery monitoring methods.

Comment: I am aware of this, but don't plan to submit. just practicing! Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've changed the method to return a dict:

```
#include "IOPowerSources.h"
#include "IOPSKeys.h"

- (NSDictionary *) batteryData
{
  CFTypeRef blob = IOPSCopyPowerSourcesInfo();
  CFArrayRef sources = IOPSCopyPowerSourcesList(blob);

  CFDictionaryRef pSource = NULL;
  const void *psValue;

  int numOfSources = CFArrayGetCount(sources);
  if (numOfSources == 0) {
    NSLog(@"Error in CFArrayGetCount");
      return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:-1], @"curCapacity", [NSNumber numberWithInt:-1], @"maxCapacity", nil];;
  }

  for (int i = 0 ; i < numOfSources ; i++)
  {
    pSource = IOPSGetPowerSourceDescription(blob, CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(sources, i));
    if (!pSource) {
      NSLog(@"Error in IOPSGetPowerSourceDescription");
          return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:-1], @"curCapacity", [NSNumber numberWithInt:-1], @"maxCapacity", nil];;
    }
    psValue = (CFStringRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(pSource, CFSTR(kIOPSNameKey));

    int curCapacity = 0;
    int maxCapacity = 0;
    double percent;

    psValue = CFDictionaryGetValue(pSource, CFSTR(kIOPSCurrentCapacityKey));
    CFNumberGetValue((CFNumberRef)psValue, kCFNumberSInt32Type, &curCapacity);

    psValue = CFDictionaryGetValue(pSource, CFSTR(kIOPSMaxCapacityKey));
    CFNumberGetValue((CFNumberRef)psValue, kCFNumberSInt32Type, &maxCapacity);

    percent = ((double)curCapacity/(double)maxCapacity * 100.0f);

    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:curCapacity], @"curCapacity", [NSNumber numberWithInt:maxCapacity], @"maxCapacity", nil];
  }
  return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:-1], @"curCapacity", [NSNumber numberWithInt:-1], @"maxCapacity", nil];;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the function as written returns only a single double representing either an error or the percentage. To return the current and max capcities you would need to either rewrite the function to return multiple values like so:

```
-(double) batteryLevel(**currentCapacity,**maxCapacity){...}
```

Or break it up into three separate functions each of which calls a separate IOPower function for each capacity sought.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried to split it up into three separate functions (see above) but I think I went about it wrongly as it still does not work. Can you show me how it should be done?

Answer (score -1):

Judging from the constants in [IOPSKeys.h](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/IOKitUser/IOKitUser-907.1.13/ps.subproj/IOPSKeys.h), it might not be possible to get a raw mAh value for the battery.

> The power source's software may specify the units for this key. The units must be consisent for all capacities reported by this power source. 
>   Clients may derive a percentage of power source battery remaining by dividing "Current Capacity" by "Max Capacity"